# GUI and Powershell script to manage mail accounts

Tags: email, powershell, xaml

I've written this rather cumbersome PowerShell script that facilitates a business use case. Because I built it off a PowerShell auditing tool I made, it was formatted differently.

What I'd like to do, in the module that launches the WPF window, is have it launch a runspace for the portion that verifies whether the mailbox is on Exchange onprem or on cloud, then launch another runspace to make the change.

However, some guides I've seen suggest that I write a C# to launch the menu, and then functionalize the actual 2-3 PowerShell sections for the C# based menu to call. (I don't know visual studio or C# well enough to do that without major heart palpitations.)

```
   function proc-input {
     Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [hashtable]$uuer
        )
    $a = 0
       $a = $b = $null
      [string]$uuss = $uuer.userooo
      [string]$usdo = $uuer.startdateooo 
      if ($uuer.enddateooo -ne $null){
      [string]$uedo = $uuer.enddateooo }
      else {$uedo = $null }
      [string]$uimo = $uuer.intmesooo 
      [string]$uemo = $uuer.extmesooo
      [bool]$glib = $uuer.halt
      $uuss = $uuss.trim()
     #   update-window "String"
     # update-window $uuss -AppendContent
       con-main
          }
    function con-main {
      try
      {
        Get-MsolDomain -ErrorAction Stop > $null
      }
      catch 
      {
        if ($cred -eq $null){
               update-window "Connecting to server to Validate, requires credentials"
          $usercredential = Get-Credential
          #import-module msonline
          import-module azureadpreview
          $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection #-SessionOption $proxysettings
          Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -allowclobber
      connect-msolservice -Credential $userCredential }
       }
      eml-valid
    }
    function eml-valid {
    $b = $a = $null
        try {
       $a = Get-Mailbox $uuss -erroraction stop
      }
      catch {
         $a = 0
      }
      if ($a -eq 0){
       $sam,$max = $uuss.split("{@}")
       try {
     $b = get-aduser $sam
      }
      catch {
        $b = 0
      }
      if ($b -eq 0) {
       update-window "$uuss,Email NOT Found! TRY: First initial last name?"
      proc-input
      }
      else {
      update-window "Legacy Email; Changing connection. Login first initial last name email : bob smith = bsmith@companyco.com"
      con-ex $glib
      }
    }
    else     {
     update-window "Setting mailbox $uuss on cloud"
     set-ooomessage $uuss $usdo $glib
          if ($glib -ne $true){
          update-window "$uuss Success, user updated in Exchange online updated" }
            }
    }
    function set-ooomessage {
      #will set out of office message if fed 3 correct strings.
       Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$user,
        [parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$startdate,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [bool]$halt
              )
      if ($halt -ne $true){
        if ($uedo -ne $null){
         Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration $user -AutoReplyState Scheduled -StartTime $startdate -EndTime $uedo -ExternalMessage $uemo -InternalMessage $uimo
    add-content $ooolog "$user,$startdate,$uedo,$uemo,$uimo"
       }
      else {
        Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration $user -AutoReplyState Scheduled -StartTime $startdate -InternalMessage $uimo -ExternalMessage $uemo
     add-content $ooolog "$user,$startdate,$uemo,$uimo"
       }
      }
      else {
      add-content $ooolog "$user,$startdate,$uemo,$uimo,test"
       update-window "Test occured $uuss NOT UPDATED"
      }
    }
    function con-ex {
      #connect exchange on prem
      $rmtest = get-pssession
    foreach ($line in $rmtest){
    $cnr = $line.computername
    $cnid = $line.id
    if ($cnr -like "outlook.office365.com")
    {
    remove-pssession $cnid}
    }
      $UserC = Get-credential
      $localEx = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://exchange.companyco.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserC
        Import-PSSession $localEx -DisableNameChecking
       set-ooomessage $uuss $usdo $glib
        if ($glib -ne $true) {
     update-window "Success: $uuss updated in Exchange On prem"}
      }
    Function Update-Window {
        Param (
            $Content,
            [switch]$AppendContent
        )
            If ($PSBoundParameters['AppendContent']) {
             $window.results.AppendText($content)
            } Else {
                $window.results.Text = $Content
            }
        }
```

** xaml.. **

```
$xaml = @'
<Window
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   MinWidth="200"
   Width ="440.172"
   SizeToContent="Height"
   Title="New Out of Office Message"
   Topmost="True" Height="313.505">
    <Grid Margin="10,40,10,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">Please enter user email. If <Bold>BOLD</Bold>, Must be filled out</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"><Bold>Email</Bold></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5"><Bold>Start Date</Bold></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">End Date</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"><Bold>Internal Message</Bold></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5"><Bold>External Message</Bold></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Margin="5">Results</TextBlock>


        <TextBox Name="TxtEmail" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"></TextBox>
        <DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" />
        <DatePicker x:Name="EndDate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" />
        <TextBox Name="TxtiMesg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="TxteMesg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name= "results" Height = "80" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="8" Width = "500"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <CheckBox x:Name="Item2" Content = 'Test'/>
            <Button Name="ButOk" MinWidth="80" Height="22" Margin="5">OK</Button>
            <Button Name="ButDone" MinWidth="80" Height="22" Margin="5">Done</Button>
            <Button Name="ButCancel" MinWidth="80" Height="22" Margin="5">Cancel</Button>
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
    function Convert-XAMLtoWindow
    {
      param
      (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $XAML
      )
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
        $reader = [XML.XMLReader]::Create([IO.StringReader]$XAML)
      $result = [Windows.Markup.XAMLReader]::Load($reader)
      $reader.Close()
      $reader = [XML.XMLReader]::Create([IO.StringReader]$XAML)
      while ($reader.Read())
      {
          $name=$reader.GetAttribute('Name')
          if (!$name) { $name=$reader.GetAttribute('x:Name') }
          if($name)
          {$result | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $name -Value $result.FindName($name) -Force}
      }
      $reader.Close()
      $result
    }
    function Show-WPFWindow
    {
      param
      (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Windows.Window]
        $Window
      )
       $result = $null
      $null = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{
        $result = $window.ShowDialog()
        Set-Variable -Name result -Value $result -Scope 1
      }.Wait()
      $result
    }
    #endregion Code Behind
    function get-userinp {
      #region Convert XAML to Window
      $window = Convert-XAMLtoWindow -XAML $xaml 
      #endregion
```

`#region Define Event Handlers
  # Right-Click XAML Text and choose WPF/Attach Events to
  # add more handlers
  $window.ButCancel.add_Click(
    {
      $window.DialogResult = $false
    }
  )

  $window.ButOk.add_Click(
    {
    $window.ButOk.isenabled = $false
    $window.ButDone.isenabled = $false
    $window.ButCancel.isenabled = $false
 #     $window.DialogResult = $true
       [hashtable]$return = @{}
       $return.userooo = $window.TxtEmail.Text 
       $return.startdateooo = $window.StartDate.SelectedDate.Date.ToShortDateString()
          if($window.EndDate.SelectedDate -ne $null){
       $return.enddateooo = $window.EndDate.SelectedDate.Date.ToShortDateString()}
       $return.extmesooo = $window.TxteMesg.Text
       $return.intmesooo = $window.TxtiMesg.Text 
           if ($window.item2.ischecked){
       $return.halt = $true}
        proc-input $return
           $sescleaner = get-pssession
foreach ($lin in $sescleaner){
$cnid = $lin.id
remove-pssession $cnid
}
       $window.ButDone.isenabled = $true
       }
  )
  $window.ButDone.add_Click(
    {
      $window.DialogResult = $true
    }
  )
    #endregion Event Handlers
     #region Manipulate Window Content
  $window.TxtiMesg.Text = 'User is out of office'
  $window.TxteMesg.Text = 'User is out of office'
  $window.TxtEmail.Text = 'test@companyco.com'
  $null = $window.TxtEmail.Focus()
  #endregion
  # Show Window
  $result = Show-WPFWindow -Window $window
}
$ooopath = "\ooolog.txt"
$ooolog = $env:temp + $ooopath
get-userinp
#con-main
#eml-valid #uncomment to test data capture loop
#con-ex`

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  I am uncertain as to whether your code accomplishes what you want it to, could you please clear that up for me?

Comment: my code currently accomplishes what it is intended to do, but not efficiently.

Comment: @PhillKenyon you could try to use jobs and synchronize their results and statuses with timer object. Manage controls and all. Your form will be responsive that way.